# How can same video appear in most popular video list of 2 different regions?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to find 10 most popular you tube videos in 2 regions. But to my surprise

**Issue 1.**
one of the videos is present in both region's most popular video list.

**Issue 2:-**
And, this video does not match with the single most popular video retrieved for region 1.

Please see the steps I followed

**Steps followed for issue1:**-

I tried for regions  r1 and r2 using following params

request 1(region:r1):-

```
      part: 'snippet,statistics',
      chart: 'mostPopular',
      kind: 'youtube#videoListResponse',
      regionCode: r1,
      maxResults: 10,
```

request 2(region:r2):-

```
      part: 'snippet,statistics',
      chart: 'mostPopular',
      kind: 'youtube#videoListResponse',
      regionCode: r2,
      maxResults: 10,
```

service url used is https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos.

I am getting video_id  "GXy1JwJ6vJ0"  in both the lists.

How is that possible?

**Steps followed for issue 2:-**
Now underlying problem is that this id "GXy1JwJ6vJ0" has as of now 6.1 m views and present in both regions r1 and r2 most popular video list. But when I searched for single most popular video in region r1 then it gives me other video with lesser number of views.

How is that possible? What's wrong here?

Comment: Can you share which regions you're using in these requests?

Comment: Note that most popular doesn't mean with most views. As far as I know the most popular filter isn't defined exactly defined by YouTube.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison : yes i searched the youtube api documentation but it doesn't clarify what exactly they mean by mostpopular videos and criteria for getting the list ? But still a video should not be present in 2 regions most popular video list, in my opinion. What do you say ?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes "IN" and "PK"

Comment: @ktayal IMO In theory some videos aren't specific to a region, so if an English video is very popular in multiple regions, then it makes sense to list it in both regions as most popular.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison , this whole confusion is because i could not find anywhere what does most popular list means ? on what basis like viewcounts, likescounts  or comments counts.....what i exactly want to know is... the list of most viewed videos in a specific country ..? most popular is creating confusions ...are there any more documentation somewhere related to this ? cud be great help.